# How to turn off parallel execution of tests for multi-project builds?

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a multi-project build with tests in sub-projects and in a parent project. The build is aggregated so that the parent project runs all tests in child projects.

I configured it so that there's no parallel execution of tests in both the sub-projects and the parent project, via

```
parallelExecution in Test := false
```

However, I have the nagging feeling that tests that span over multiple projects are ran in parallel. In the case of one of the sub-projects this is a problem because it mutates state in a test database concurrently, leading to the test to fail.

Any ideas as to how to globally switch of parallel execution of tests, between projects?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I think you can apply a setting across projects using scope `ThisBuild`, like

```
parallelExecution in ThisBuild := false
```

I don't know if you can combine that with scope `Test`, but it might not be necessary.

Comment: Sorry, I am kinda new to Scala and faced the same problem - where should I put this line? To which file of the project?

Comment: The easiest is to put it into `build.sbt` (that file is used even if you have a full configuration in `project/Build.scala`)

Comment: Thanks! I ve figured it myself, too hasty to ask instead of thinking :). Anyway thank you

Comment: Anywhere in particular in build.sbt?

Answer (score 23):

To restrict the number of concurrently executing tests in all projects, use:

```
concurrentRestrictions in Global += Tags.limit(Tags.Test, 1)
```

See [sbt documentation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Parallel-Execution.html#Defining+Restrictions)

See [discussion](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/1886)

Answer (score 10):

This worked for me in 1.1.0:

`Test / parallelExecution := false`

Answer (score 4):

See my answer here [How to run subprojects tests (including setup methods) sequentially when testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18895063/how-to-run-subprojects-tests-including-setup-methods-sequentially-when-testing/27690751#27690751)

There is another way to prevent parallel execution. You can make the test tasks of the different projects depend on each other:

```
test in Project2 := (test in Project2).dependsOn(test in Project1).value
parallelExecution in Test in Project2 := false
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me: I am getting `References to undefined settings: Project2/*:test from Project2/*:test (/Users/the21st/Work/Project2/build.sbt:36) Did you mean Project2/web-assets-test:test ?`

Answer (score 2):

The "modern" (i.e. sbt 1.x) equivalent of disabling parallel execution in `Test` scope is to add the following to your `build.sbt`:

```
Global / concurrentRestrictions += Tags.limit(Tags.Test, 1)
```

For those not familiar with sbt syntax, in context you want to do something like:

```
lazy val main = project
  .in(file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "foo",
    // more settings
    // ...
    Global / concurrentRestrictions += Tags.limit(Tags.Test, 1)
  )
```

From the [tags and rules](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Parallel-Execution.html#Built-in+Tags+and+Rules) section of sbt docs.

p.s. quite a useful setting for ScalaTest, particularly around setup/teardown logic during database testing. Fixes some quite puzzling non-deterministic errors that you'll ineviitably hit with parallel execution enabled.

Comment: This is the solution I was looking for but, interestingly, I did find that it only worked once I had removed the `Test / parallelExecution := false` rule from the sub-projects that were aggregated by the parent.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility, based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/27068019/1922026, is to define a command alias in the root project:

```
.settings(addCommandAlias("test", ";s1/test;s2/test;s3/test"): _*)
```

where s1, s2 and s3 are the sub-projects. When you are in root project and run "test" the tests will be executed sequentially and in the order defined.

Answer (score 1):

You can try also `Global / parallelExecution := false`