# How to run subprojects tests (including setup methods) sequentially when testing

Tags: scala, sbt

**EDIT4** Most of the text below the horizontal rule doesn't have anything to do with the real problem. At the beginning I thought forking is the problem, but that is not true.

I'm trying to run all the tests of an aggregates subprojects. Before all the tests in a subproject a setup method should run, and after the tests in a subproject a cleanup method should run.

When running the test task for the aggregate project, I expect the following sequence

- setup method of project A is called
- tests for project A are executed
- cleanup method for project A is called
- the same for project B

But the sequence is:

- setup methods of project A and B are called
- tests of project A are executed
- tests of project B are executed
- cleanup methods of project A and B are called

A build script having this behaviour can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/choedl/6634961).

How can I fix this problem to get my expected sequence?

---

I'm using forking to run the tests in my subprojects.
  For every subproject a mongo db is started before the tests and stopped
  after the tests.

The tests within one project run sequentially; this works well if I run the tests for a single project.

But if I run the task **test** for project root (the aggregate containing the sub projects), 
  I want the forked jvms to be started sequentially, i.e.

1. the jvm for project A is forked and its tests are executed
2. the jvm for project B is forked and its tests are executed
3. ...

But it looks like the jvms are started in parallel; this is not what I want.

I tried the following (which should be set to 1 already, according to the documentation):

```
  concurrentRestrictions in Test := Seq(
    Tags.limit(Tags.ForkedTestGroup, 1)
  )
```

But it didn't work. Directly after starting the test task, the following is
printed (before any test log is printed) from my setup method:

```
startupDb, thread name = pool-4-thread-5 
startupDb, thread name = pool-4-thread-7 
startupDb, thread name = pool-4-thread-2 
startupDb, thread name = pool-4-thread-6 
startupDb, thread name = pool-4-thread-8
startupDb, thread name = pool-4-thread-3 
startupDb, thread name = pool-4-thread-9
```

These are my test related settings:

```
parallelExecution in Test := false,
testOptions in Test += Tests.Setup( () => MongoTest.startupDb() ),
testOptions in Test += Tests.Cleanup( () => MongoTest.shutdownDb() ),
fork in Test := true,
concurrentRestrictions in Test := Seq(
  Tags.limit(Tags.ForkedTestGroup, 1)
)
```

It's important for me to use forking, but in the way as described above.

I'm using sbt 0.13.0 on Windows 7.

**EDIT** I created a gist with a [sample build](https://gist.github.com/choedl/6634961).

**EDIT2** In the [documentation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Testing#forking-tests) it says:

> Control the number of forked JVMs allowed to run at the same time by setting the limit on Tags.ForkedTestGroup tag, which is 1 by default

So this should work theoretically.
Is this a bug? If not, how can I manage to do that?

**EDIT3** It looks like forking is not the problem. The problem is that the setup methods are called immediately for all subprojects.

Comment: Why do the projects have to be tested sequentially?  Is it because there is only one mongodb resource, which prevents them being used in parallel (namespace conflicts, resoure locks or whatever)?

Comment: Yes, and you can not use the same port for the mongo instances.

Comment: Is it necessary that mongo tests are spread across multiple subprojects?

Comment: Yes, it is necessary.

Comment: This question sounds like [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11899723/how-to-turn-off-parallel-execution-of-tests-for-multi-project-builds?rq=1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11899723/how-to-turn-off-parallel-execution-of-tests-for-multi-project-builds?rq=1)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hmm.  Trivial answer convert to comment.  It sounds like you are asking the same question that got solved in the other question (see comments).  The answer seems to be

```
parallelExecution in ThisBuild := false
```

and I found another blog post that suggested

```
parallelExecution in Global := false
```

to be the answer.  The "Global" answer also suggested that would turn off parallel execution for things like compilation but that's probably less important than running tests.

Comment: Thanks, I did not think of that. I thought parallelExecution in Test := false is sufficient.

Comment: This is a correct answer, but `in ThisBuild` still disables parallel compilations. See https://groups.google.com/d/topic/simple-build-tool/loZVOeF5sfk/discussion
It's still not solved

Answer (score 5):

As of sbt 0.12, you can make all test tasks in all subprojects run serially with this setting:

```
concurrentRestrictions in Global += Tags.limit(Tags.Test, 1)
```

(`Tags.Test` is a built in semantic tag for all test tasks).

See: [Parallel-Execution](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Parallel-Execution.html) in the SBT manual.

Answer (score 2):

There is another way to prevent parallel execution. You can make the test tasks of the different projects depend on each other:

```
test in Project2 := (test in Project2).dependsOn(test in Project1).value
parallelExecution in Test in Project2 := false
```